# azure blob video not showing video only plays audio

Tags: javascript, angularjs, azure, html5-video

I have uploaded video using C# and saved on azure storage with content type set video/mp4. When I want to play the video on browser the video is not shown only audio is playing.

URL: http://snapshotprojectmedia.blob.core.windows.net/projectmediafiles/2.mp4

You can simply navigate this link in chrome to test.

Comment: I can see the video. Just tried it in mobile safari.

Comment: thanks, it also works on IE edge but not on chrome or firefox in desktop

Comment: I also tried it and was able to reproduce this issue with Chrome in 2 different OS. I read somewhere that Chrome has removed some codecs and that could be the reason for video not showing.